# ipython import modules fine but python import fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, version, importerror

there.
I'm not quite sure what I have done recently that cause the problem as mentioned in the title. I usually run the simple code in ipython, and run longer scripts use python command. However, just now it seems that `python somescript.py` doesn't work well if some modules are imported in the `somescript.py` file. For example, say it contains `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, when I run `python somescript.py` in the terminal, I will get an error message: 
`ImportError: no module named matplotlib`. This is weird since when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` under `ipython`, it works fine, no error.

And I checked that the python version and path is different from ipython. ipython has several more paths that python, and the version is 2.7.11, while python is 2.7.10. So, what should I do to permanently resolve this issue? Add the other paths to python? How can I make sure that they import the same modules each time? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've got two copies of Python installed somehow. You probably want to get rid of one, and ensure that the other one is on `$PATH`. You can see where the Python used by IPython is with `sys.version`.

Comment: yup i agree with @ThomasK , it's an issue with different version of python.